# Pull down for more cells

Tags: c#, ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I scoured the Internet for a code snippet or recipe which detects whether or not the user scrolled to the last cell on a `UItableview` on monotouch. I am not using a `TableSource.Cs` to load my objects either.

Comment: Interesting. Did you find what you were searching for? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If you are not using a TableSource what are you using?  Can you show your code?

Comment: Did you try to read the vertical offset of the table view? pseudo code: if contentsize.height - uiscreen.mainscreen.bounds.height >= offset.y => scrolled at least to bottom.